# Matplotlib very slow - can't keep up with incoming Arduino data

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib

I have an Arduino connected to my laptop and try to plot some numbers as they come from it, using Python and the Martplotlib library.
The Arduino sends two numbers (`arrays1` & `arrays2`) and I want them to be plotted (as they come) above a background plot that is configured on the Python code (`y=np.array`). The below code works but I face some problems with the speed of Matplotlib plotting.

When I send data from the Arduino with a `delay(1500)` everything works fine, they re plotted as they come.
When I send data from the Arduino every second, it starts plotting ok the first 30 values but then the plotting of the rest 18 values is delayed, happening every around 1.5 seconds. 
If I don't maximize the plotting window, or remove the `axvspan` command, it seems to be able to plot the values every 1 second! 
If I send values from the Arduino with a `delay(100)`, the Matplotlib cannot plot them more frequently than every 0.5-1 seconds.

Is it normal for Matplotlib to be that slow?
I am really new to Python and Matplotlib so I do not know if I have made any mistake that may delays the plotting.

Python Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import serial
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

second=0
x=np.arange(0,48)
y=np.array([33, 29, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 22, 24, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43,
47, 45, 42, 41, 39, 38, 39, 38, 40, 43, 46, 48, 46, 44, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
48, 49, 52, 56, 60, 62, 61, 58, 53, 49, 45, 40, 33])
f=interp1d(x,y,kind='cubic')
xint=np.arange(0,47,0.01)
yint = f(xint)

arduinoData = serial.Serial('com4',9600) #Opening the connection to the serial port

plt.ion() #Activating matplotlib's interactive mode
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.window.state('zoomed')

while True:
    while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0): #Wait here until there is data
        pass #do nothing
    arduinoString = arduinoData.readline() #read the line of text from the serial port
    dataArray = arduinoString.split(',')   #Split it into an array called dataArray
    num1 = int( dataArray[0])            #Convert first element to int num1
    num2 = int( dataArray[1])            #Convert second element to int num2
    if num1 == 0 & num2 == 0:   #when it gets 0 and 0 from Arduino, clear the existing graph, plot the background plot and the axis
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(x,y,'o',c='b')
        plt.plot(xint,yint,'-r')
        plt.title('My plot')
        plt.xlabel('Axis X')
        plt.ylabel('Axis Y)')
        plt.xlim(-0.5, 50)
        plt.ylim(0, 90)
        plt.grid()
        second=0
    else:                            # start getting the numbers that should be plotted above the background and draw the plot
        plt.plot(second, num1, 'm+') 
        plt.plot(second, num2, 'kx')
        plt.axvspan(0, second, alpha=0.5, color='cyan')
        second += 1
        fig = plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.04)
```

Arduino code:

```
int i=0;
int reset=0;
int array1[48]={38, 30, 28, 27, 26, 25, 25, 24, 23, 24, 27, 29, 33, 37, 40, 46, 49, 47, 44, 43, 41, 41, 42, 40, 43, 46, 49, 52, 49, 48, 47, 48, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 55, 59, 61, 65, 64, 61, 57, 50, 48, 42, 38}; 

int array2[48]={29, 26, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 19, 22, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 42, 39, 37, 36, 35, 37, 36, 37, 40, 42, 44, 43, 40, 39, 40, 42, 42, 43, 45, 46, 48, 53, 58, 59, 58, 54, 50, 48, 42, 38, 31};


void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600); //turn on serial connection
}

void loop(){
  reset = 0;
  Serial.print(reset);
  Serial.print(" , ");
  Serial.println(reset);
  delay(2000);
  for (i=0;i<48;i++)
  {
    Serial.print(array1[i]);
    Serial.print(" , ");
    Serial.println(array2[i]);
    delay(1000); //Pause between data sending
    }
}
```

Comment: `matplotlib` is a library designed to produce publication quality output on a largish number of different backends, with a fine-grained control on every detail of the graph.  On the other hand, there are libraries designed to use only one (or a few) backend and that are optimized for speed, one name that spring to (my) mind is [guiqwt](http://code.google.com/p/guiqwt/). Even if it is possible that some sort of blooper in your code slows downs the rendering,  you'll have to wait for a more competent person to be sure of it. OTOH there are faster plotting libraries than `matplotlib`

Comment: 1 second is very slow, even for matplotlib.  If you want an answer, though, you should post a **minimal** pure python example that exhibits the same problem.  But, in general, what you show isn't the best way to make a plot that's updated in real time.